# If an isomorphism can be expressed as a composition of morphisms, what can we say about its components?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is an isomomorphism, and $f=g\circ h$ where $h:X\to Z$ and $g:Z\to Y$. Can we infer that either of these component morphisms is an isomorphism as well? And does this change depending on the category?

Comment: We cannot. Think of categories with a null object, like the category of abelian groups. (And it doesn’t work for most concrete categories like $\mathrm{Set}$ itself.)

Comment: What if I am in the category of sets?

Comment: Think of the counterexample in $\mathrm{Ab}$ as a counterexample in $\mathrm{Set}$.

Comment: Actually there are some categories in which this can be done: for example every preordered set (thought as a category) has this property.

Comment: There are some implications when $f=g\circ h$. If $f$ is epic, then $g$ is epic. If $f$ is a retraction, then $g$ is a retraction. Dually, if $f$ is monic, then so is $h$, and if $f$ is a section, then so is $h$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any category:

We can say that $h$ is mono and $g$ is epi
and if one of the 2 components is an iso, then the other must be an iso too.

Comment: More is true: h is split mono and g is split epi.